# How are complex executable files written?

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, exe, executable

*voting down this question is fine obviously, but please tell me why it's stupid or otherwise undesirable, I'm just trying to learn*

My aim is to comprehend complex programs like Chrome.

I understand that these files could simply be a few lines to extract files to a specified location, edit the registry, or preform a simple task (like .bat files).

But what about complex .exe files like acrobat.exe or game.exe (like..... bioshock.exe)?

Correct me if I'm wrong:

I'd assume that it would work just the same like 
 load certain files into the ram and into other files.
It would store all possible commands or point to somewhere that does ( Right Mouse Click = Select/Fire Gun)
But how do the companies make these .exe?
Can/Are any of them coded in java?
And how can someone else hack into them to change a few things? Like the controversy about SimCity offline mode (though I don't think the hack was in the .exe)
Last I remember, you couldn't just open an .exe like an archive right?

Answer (score 2):

Writing a *complete* answer to your question is very difficult to do. However lemme try to give you a glimpse how *complex* ".exe's" are written.

Say you want to write a program that writes letters. You will first develop something called `Software requirement specification` for this. You will need to do some `requirement gathering` for this.

So, you will start to jot down:
1. Have an option to add a recipient.
2. Have a facility to add text to the letter.
3. Have a mechanism to sign the letter.

and so on ...

Then you will begin to code.

First you will start off by writing some code to match your requirements. (your complex exe is starting to take shape; yay !)

Then you will probably need to rethink your original strategy (unless you are an expert) and rewrite some of the code .. this process will continue iteratively.

Till now you will have a bunch of "source files" :

1. a java program that accepts some text from the user.
2. a java program that uses [POP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) to send emails (electronic letters that is :))
3. a java program that uses [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) to assign a [digital certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) to "sign" your letter.

But now you will realise that you have made 3 programs that have 3 main programs. But you need to do the things at one go ! So, you will remove the main programs and write a "main class" that creates objects of the three source files. Your main program might look something like this:

```
AcceptText ap = new AcceptText("My letter content");
Letter L = new Letter();
L.addContent(ap);
Signature S = new Signature();
S.sign();
L.addSignature(S);
L.send();
```

Now you will compile this into an executable or an executable jar. You wmight even feel like adding some GUI to it using swing or similar.

Thus you have your first complex exe ready ! Run it to send emails on your own !
Now when you look at something like bioshock.exe, they are made out of thousands of source files, all neatly put together. They also have a ton of artwork, animations, clips, sounds added to them. Little by little, they create such complex programs. There is no secret technique. You can learn the basics of creating exe's very easily. But it will take extreme perseverance and sincerity to develop something large scale.

If you are really interested, learn 2-3 programming languages thoroughly. Then learn some "frameworks" or libraries. These can be something like graphics libraries like [opengl] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL). Slowly but surely; you will learn how to make one of those complex exe's yourself. It takes time and a lot of effort. Happy coding ! and welcome to the club.

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to write that, actually didn't lose me. When I was an avid gamer, I modded all the time, and dabbled with 3ds + maya on a few occasions, thus understand resource files and how they function pretty well, I like to think.   And yea, I planned on following something similar to your suggestion, thanks.   Just one question, is it fair to say that more/less the exe's I'm referring to are a huge collection of "if" and "when" instructional code, (other than pictures and whatever other resources that maybe inside of them)??

Comment: yes, your exe's are definitely going to have a lot of conditional expressions. But its not all that they have.